# Android Device Monitor "data" folder is empty

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have tested creating, inserting and retrieving data into my apps db, and know it works through usage of Log statements.

However, I wish to expedite testing and use the Android Device Monitor. However, though the db exists and data is stored, when accessing below, the `data` folder is empty:

[image]

Why would this be the case? How can this be configured to show the db file and contents?

Comment: In debug mode, this answer helped me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42865585/3520656

Answer (score 44):

### Solving the issue using an emulator

The folder `/data` can be empty because you are missing the proper permissions. To solve it, I had to execute the following commands.

```
adb shell
su
```

Those commands starts a shell in the emulator and grant you root rights. The command `adb` is located in the folder `platform-tools` of the Android SDK, typically installed in `~/Library/Android/sdk/` on MacOS.

```
chmod -R 777 /data
```

Modify the permissions of the folder (and subfolders recursively) `/data` in order to make them appear in the tool A*ndroid Device Monitor*.

```
adb root
```

Finally, this command restarts `adb` as root. Be careful, it only works on development builds (typically emulators builds).

Afterwards, you can see the content of the folder `/data` and transfer the data located in. You can do it in console as well, using `adb pull <remote> <locale>`, such as:

```
adb pull /data/data/<app name>/databases/<database> .
```

Answer (score 24):

In addition to @Steven K's answers: If you want to gain access to your data without having to root your real device you need to run your app in an **emulator** with **API 23** (or lower). It is a [known problem](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221732) that APIs above 23 can cause problems when deploying Android Device Monitor.

Answer (score 10):

If anyone is having the stated problem, follow below steps in terminal window:

1. Navigate to /Users/***Username***/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
2. Execute ./adb root

That's it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 8):

It isn't empty....you just don't have permission to view that folder on a device.

Try it in a simulator and it will work for you since you have root access.

Comment: I am testing on my personal device.  How can I gain root access?

Comment: You can view database only in rooted phones.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways if you want to browse your device data (data/data) folder.

1. You need to have a phone with root access in order to browse the data folder using ADM(Android Device Monitor).

> ADM location - (YOUR_SDK_PATH\Android\sdk\tools)

2. You need to be running ADB in root mode, do this by executing: `adb root`

If you just want to see your **DB & Tables** then the esiest way is to use `Stetho`. Pretty cool tool for every Android developer who uses `SQLite` buit by `Facobook developed`.

`Steps to use the tool`

1. Add below dependeccy in your application`s gradle file (Module: app)

> 'compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'

2. Add below lines of code in your Activity onCreate() method

> ```
> @Override
>  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>  Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
>  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>  }
> ```

Now, build your application & When the app is running, you can browse your app database, by opening chrome  in the url:

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

Screenshots of the same are as below_

> ChromeInspact

[image: ChromeInspact]

> Your DB

[image: Your DB]

Hope this will help all! :)

Answer (score 5):

It may be easier to store the database in a public folder during development.

Or you can see this post :

[How to access data/data folder in Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13006315/1922200)

Comment: Can you please outline how to accomplish this?

Comment: File dbfile = new File("/sdcard/mydb.sqlite" ); SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null); System.out.println("Its open? " + db.isOpen

Answer (score 3):

In cmd GoTo:

```
C:\Users\UserName\android-sdks\platform-tools
```

Execute:

```
adb root
```

Done

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with `API_25`, it didn't work for me.

Configure an `API_23 emulator`, it will work on `API_23`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows follow these instructions step by step:

1. Launch your app in android emulator.
2. Then open command prompt as an administrator and navigate to the sdk path for example `cd  C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools`
3. Type `adb root`
4. Then type `adb  pull /data/data/ name-of-your-package /databases/name-of-your-database`
5. You'll find your database located in the folder called `platform-tools`.

Then you can install Sqlite Manager extension in Google Chrome via chrome webstore and use it to view and manage your exported database.

In case you have a rooted phone you can follow the same instructions as above.