# file explorer in AVD emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

Someone knows why I couldn't access to all data under **Data folder** in `file explorer` into `Android device monitor`?

I have started android 8 AVD emulator on Android studio. Now I want to see sql database under **Data folder** but unfortunately Data folder is empty or it is not opened!!!!

[image]

on the right at the top DDMS is clicked as you can see.
I am using

```
android studio Android Studio 3.0
Build #AI-171.4408382, built on October 20, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603355/android-device-monitor-data-folder-is-empty

Comment: when I got this error when I run super user:`1|generic_x86:/ $ su
/system/bin/sh: su: not found
127|generic_x86:/ $
`