# data folder not opening in android device monitor API 19

Tags: sqlite

I'm using usb debugging(SM - G335h version 4.4.2 API 19) and I want to export the database from android studio but the data folder can't unfold . anyone knows how to fix this?
 I've tried rooting my phone using adb root but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A way around this would be to copy the database file to an accessible location from within the App.

Such a location, for example, could be the downloads folder, which can be determined/accessed by using something like:-

```
File yourdir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath());
```

- Note you'd need to set appropriate permissions.

You could get the Database location using :-

```
Context.getDatabasePath("your_database_name");
```

e.g. a very basic/minimal example could be :-

```
    File from = new File(a_suitable_context.getDatabasePath("your_database_name").getPath());
    File to = new File(a_suitable_context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + File.separator + "your_db_savename");
    byte[] bffr = new byte[1024];
    FileInputStream fsfrom;
    FileOutputStream fsto;
    try {
        fsfrom = new FileInputStream(from);
        fsto = new FileOutputStream(to);
        while(fsfrom.read(bffr) > 0) {
            fsto.write(bffr);
        }
        fsto.flush();
        fsfrom.close();
        fsto.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You could then access this file from AS's device explorer. e.g. :-

[image]

- Note this uses a sub-directory within the Downloads folder.
- Note `a_suitable_context`, `your_database_name` and `your_db_savename` would be suitable values that you would supply (the latter could both be the database name).
- If the dabase is quite large then you may wish to increase the bfrr size.

You may also be able to use the solution from here [Android Device Monitor “data” folder is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603355/android-device-monitor-data-folder-is-empty)